# Recipient-Domain-Mismatch Mailchimp

Tags: c#, .net, mailchimp, restsharp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm currently trying to send e-mails with Mailchimp and have a verified `example.com` domain. The issue being that I try sending an email from `no-reply@example.com` to a list of emails with domains like `gmail.com` or `outlook.com` but Mailchimp returns a `recipient-domain-mismatch` error. Is there a configuration or extra step to allow sending emails to other domains?

Full request

```
{
    "key": "**********************",
    "message": {
        "html": "content",
        "subject": "subject",
        "from_email": "no-reply@example.com",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "client@gmail.com",
                "type": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Full response

```
[
    {
        "email": "client@gmail.com",
        "status": "rejected",
        "_id": "********************************",
        "reject_reason": "recipient-domain-mismatch"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reason for this error could be:

You are currently on a free plan so you are not allowed to send emails to addresses outside your verified domain. The restriction is lifted when upgrade to a paid plan.

Check the limitations of a demo plan on mailchimp's [Transactional Email Demo article](https://mailchimp.com/help/transactional-email-demo/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20send%20up%20to%20500%20transactional%20emails%20to%20any%20email%20address%20on%20your%20verified%20domain.%20Read%20more%20about%20domain%20verification%20and%20authentication%20here.).

Comment: Thanks for responding, I eventually figured that out in another forum.